# Delphi GDI+ find point on an arc using the known rectangle and angle

Tags: delphi, math, gdi+

Using GDI+ in Delphi 10.2.3: I have an elliptical (not circular) arc drawn from a rectangular RectF and defined start and swept angles using DrawArcF.  I need to be able to find any point along the centerline of the arc (regardless of pen width) based just on the degrees of the point - e.g., if the arc starts at 210 for 120 degrees, I need to find the point at, say, 284 degrees, relative to the RectF.

In this case, the aspect ratio of the rectangle remains constant regardless of its size, so the shape of the arc should remain consistent as well, if that makes a difference.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Would you add a drawing showing the arc and his parameters (rectangle start and swept angles) and what exactly you are looking for? Edit your question to add the drawing.

Comment: @MBo it’s a radial angle (where 2.Pi = 360 degrees)

Comment: @R. Hoek  Sadly, no. Look at the end of the page given by Olivier: [The parameter t section](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamellipse.html) or picture near formula 58 [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html)

Comment: Is your arc axis aligned? Are the sweep angles real angles or stretched (so if you stretch your ellipse to circle then the angles will be matching)?. you can test it with +/- 45 deg angles for axis aligned ellipse and render 45  deg lines if they overlap exactly or not ... because the math involved is different for the case if they are stretched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parametric equation for axis-aligned ellipse centered at `cx, cy` with semiaxes `a,b` against angle `Fi` is:

```
t = ArcTan2(a * Sin(Fi), b * Cos(Fi))
x = cx + a * Cos(t)
y = cy + b * Sin(t)
```

*(I used `atan2` to get rid off `atan` range limitation/sign issues)*

---

Note that parameter `t` runs through the same range `0..2*Pi` but differs from true angle `Fi` (they coincide at angles `k*Pi/2`).
Picture of `Fi/t` ratio for `b/a=0.6` [from Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html) (near formula 58)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is accurate enough for my needs.